How to get first element from json using SQL query
I have a json in the below format in a table in column item_details and I am trying to get the rows with category = drawing-room. I have tried the below approach but getting null in result. Requesting to please suggest. Thanks!
JSON
"discount": [
        {
            "target": {
                "item": [
                    {
                        "category": "drawing-room",

SQL query:
select 
    object
from
    DATA, JSON(item_details->>'discount') as object
where 
    (object->>'discount[0].target.item[0].category' = 'drawing-room');


Please share sample data set @astar

Plese share the input data https://dbfiddle.uk/3aMmxpPT

Which dbms are you using? The syntax above is product specific.

I think you are type it incorrectly.
Try this
SELECT object
FROM DATA, JSON_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(item_details->'discount') AS discounts
WHERE discounts->'target'->'item'->0->>'category' = 'drawing-room';

Hope this help.

I am getting SQL Error [42833] : function json_array_elements(jsonb) does not exist..in both SQL and POSTGRESQL

resolved - jsonb_path_exists(item_detail, '$.discount[].target.item[].category ? (@ == 'drawing-room')'); ..hope this helps somebody
